# Make cells automatically shrink to fit text in OpenOffice spreadsheet

Tags: openoffice, spreadsheet

Is there a way to get the widths of cells to automatically shrink themselves to fit the longest line in a column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select the cells, then go to **Format > Column > Optimal Width**, then press **OK**.

Comment: Sorry but you still need to set the width which is not automaticly IMO.